# Downsides of JSON in GET Query String

Tags: html, json, query-string

I know this isn't standard practice, but bear with me.  What are the downsides of using JSON inside a GET query string?

I'm using Node.js as a backend so it's pretty easy to encode and decode the JSON into an actual object.  Using JSON to transmit data via query string would also make it very easy for the front-end to decode and use as well without requiring an AJAX request hidden inputs or any inline JS.

That being said, I'm not 100% if there would be any real downsides.  The only thing I could think of would be cross-browser compatibility.  Anyone else see an issue with using this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I'm guessing none.  This is assuming there is an easy way to convert query string to JSON (there is, it's `JSON.parse()`).